# Can't load operating system

Tags: aosp, google-pixel-3a-xl

I recently flashed a local build of AOSP to a Pixel 3a XL.  After rebooting and re-locking the bootloader I get the following error:

> can't load operating system

Any suggestions to resolve this?

The steps which got me here: I downloaded and installed a factory image for 'bonito', flashed to the Pixel 3a XL, and after rebooting everything works fine.

I then built and flashed AOSP from Build: QQ2A.200501.001.B2 with TAGNAME:  android-10.0.0_r35 via the usual:

```
choosecombo 1 aosp_bonito user
m
```

and then:

`fastboot flashall -w`

The result is the error above.  Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: A local build is not signed by Google hence a locked bootloader will refuse to load this operating system.

Comment: I wrote in my question that the bootloader is unlocked.

Comment: Okay, I implied.  I stated I had "re-locked."